# Checkbox checked? webView query Calabash-Android

Tags: calabash, calabash-android

Is there any way to determine if a checkbox is checked in a webView?

Below is the query for the `remember_me checkbox` The `value` does not change because this is the value submitted with the form.

Any ideas?

`irb(main):032:0> query("webView css:'#remember_me'")
[
    [0] {
              "class" => "",
           "nodeType" => "ELEMENT_NODE",
                 "id" => "remember_me",
        "textContent" => "",
               "html" => "<input type=\"checkbox\" id=\"remember_me\" value=\"1\" name=\"rm\">",
               "rect" => {
              "bottom" => 191,
                   "y" => 609,
               "right" => 23,
                   "x" => 30,
            "center_x" => 48,
               "width" => 39,
              "height" => 39,
                 "top" => 178,
                "left" => 10,
            "center_y" => 627
        },
              "value" => "1",
           "nodeName" => "INPUT",
            "webView" => "webview"
    }
]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calabash-Android does not currently support invoking methods on a webview element using the query syntax. You can, however, invoke javascript in the webview to get your result.

```
evaluate_javascript("webView", "return document.getElementById('remember_me').checked;")
```